# Looking for horizontal PC Case that fits into this furniture

Tags: case

I'm looking for PC horizontal case that will fit into this [image: Furniture hole]

It is hard to find one. So I'm looking for the horizontal PC case that will support:

- front intake 140mm fans with dust filter
- back 140mm fan for output hot air (with optional dust filter too)
- front optionally should have the possibility to add at least 280mm or longer radiator for water cooling.
- the case must be working in horizontal mode
- it could be nice if I have in front power button and some usb 3.0 ports.
- should fit into this hole and occupy as much space as possible
- should support micro-atx and mini atx
- should support normal atx power supply with length at least 180mm
- the case should have maximized height so I can put on my CPU 150mm height cooler.

I'm not interested in led's, glass panels at all.

Any advices?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to find a case that is flush with your dimensions. I suspect most manufacturers of small profile motherboards will not design their cases as large as you have specified. 'Mini Tower' has the [closest average case dimension](http://www.xoxide.com/buy-computer-cases.html) to what you want. Perhaps you could consider buying a small profile case and building some other wood/metal spacer to make the system flush?

Comment: You don't buy a case that fits this cabinet, you buy a case and then build or buy a cabinet that can fit it. There is no case (even HTPC cases) that fulfill all of your requirements and measures 160mm tall. I mean jeez man you want 140mm intake fans? You're only leaving 20mm of total overhead in the chassis dimensions to *barely* fit in that cabinet! A 150mm cooler? You literally cannot do that, the backplate for the mobo, standoffs, and the mobo itself will easily combine for more than 10mm. What you are asking for doesn't exist because it's physically impossible.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It is always good to ask :) I'll build my own case for this cabinet then :)

Comment: Seconding the general consensus here. If you want a case that'll fit within the dimensions above, I'm happy to make some recommendations, but there's no way you'll get everything you're asking for. Making your own case built into the cabinet actually seems like a relatively clean solution.

Comment: That space is large enough for a 3U server case. There might be a server case out there that fits most of what you want.